# Why is $\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\int M dx = \int \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}dx$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, differential

$M$ is a function of $x$ and $y$. I'm getting this question from looking at the solution of the exact equation $M \mathrm{dx} + N\mathrm{dy} = 0$.

Comment: See the [Leibniz integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)